# Can we access static members from a null reference? If yes, why is this allowed?

Tags: java, reference, static, null

Can we access static members from a null reference in Java? If yes, why is this allowed? And how does it work internally?

Comment: Please be more specific with your post. like which language,code snippet etc

Answer (score 2):

Yes;
"Java allows static field access through null reference".

The reason:

In Java there is no need to object instance to resolve static field. 
Access to static field is handled by getstatic instruction and it does not require an object instance. It uses run time constant pool to resolve the field.

References:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getstatic

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html